# Connecting R to ServiceNow ODBC

Tags: r, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I'm struggling a bit with how to connect R to ServiceNow ODBC.

The closest solution I found is https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/servicenow-odbc-r.rst, but it's using some paid software dependencies to make it work, which I think unnecessary.

If someone else has managed to set up a connection between R and ServiceNow, I would like to learn how.

Comment: Have you tried using the official ODBC driver distributed by ServiceNow? See https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-application-development/page/integrate/odbc-driver/concept/c_ODBCDriver.html

Comment: @JoshNerius, yes thanks for the reply. I found about the ServiceNow ODBC. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ServiceNow provides its own ODBC driver. Once installed, you can connect to the ServiceNow instance using DBI library.

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={ServiceNow ODBC Driver 64-bit};", timeout = 10)
```